# Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert "" to number; given string terraform eks modules

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws

I've created following eks cluster with terraform eks module.

```
module "myeks" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  cluster_name    = var.project
  version         = "7.0.1"
  cluster_version = var.eks_version
  subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.subnet_ids.ids
  vpc_id          = var.vpc_id

  worker_groups = [
    {
      name          = "worker-group-1"
      instance_type = "m5.large"
      asg_max_size  = 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But problem is when I run that code in gitlabci, I've encountered following error message.

```
Error: Invalid function argument
  on .terraform/modules/myeks/data.tf line 6, in locals:
   6:     var.worker_ami_name_filter_windows : "Windows_Server-2019-English-Core-EKS_Optimized-${tonumber(var.cluster_version) >= 1.14 ? var.cluster_version : 1.14}-*"
    |----------------
    | var.cluster_version is ""
Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert "" to number; given string
must be a decimal representation of a number.
Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
  on .terraform/modules/myeks/data.tf line 25, in data "aws_ami" "eks_worker":
  25: data "aws_ami" "eks_worker" {
```

But when I do `terraform plan` in local machine, it's working fine.

That's my tfvars.

```
vpc_id        = "vpc-xxxxx"
environment   = "dev"
eks_version   = "1.17"
project       = "mypro"
```

Comment: What is your `var.eks_version`? seems to be empty

Comment: @Marcin I've edited my question.

Comment: If it worked in local and has issues in gitlabci, then You may have a duplicate variable eks_version somewhere and an empty value is getting passed. You can cross check the config once or may be you can comment out the module code and try to output the value of eks_version to see what being passed

Comment: @Marcin I found that problem that forgot to map .tfvars in gitlabci? Can you post your comment as answer and I'll mark as correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to the fact that `var.eks_version` was empty. This was caused by **not mapping** `.tfvars` in `gitlabci`.

The **solution** was to add the missing mapping in `gitlabci`.